# Why some of command path are not showed completely on aix?

Tags: command, aix, ps

I'm struggling the result of "ps -ef" command on AIX.
the problem is on a special daemon that I made.
in the result of ps -ef command, except this daemon, the other daemons and running commands are OK.
it means I can see their full command path and arguments also.
But, the daemon that I made is not showed completely, like below.
even if the daemon has some of problem in its code,
if it is started successfully, I should be able to see the full command of it by 'ps -ef' command, I think.

```
....
    root 368684 266450   0  11:09:44  pts/0  0:00 -ksh
    root 372772 176246   0  11:09:21      -  0:00 /usr/sbin/qdaemon
    root 377074      1   0  11:09:28      -  0:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/NSCAUD/nscaudrun.sh
  inst97 380928      1   0  11:09:16      -  0:00 /opt/IBM/db2/V9.7/itma/aix526/ud/bin/kuddb2 AIX61TL03_in
    root 385244      1   0  11:09:13      -  0:00 /usr/bin/cimlistener
    root 389320 405704   0  11:09:01      -  0:00 /opt/freeware/cimom/pegasus/bin/cimservera
    root 397556 176246   0  11:09:22      -  0:00 /usr/sbin/writesrv
    root 405704      1   0  11:08:56      -  0:06 [cimserve]
    root 409816 176246   0  11:09:53      -  0:00 /usr/sbin/rsct/bin/vac8/IBM.CSMAgentRMd
    root 446630      1   0  11:14:38      -  0:01 /usr/maxigent50
....
```

the problem is the last one. this is not a display size problem.
the full command of the pid 446630 process in the above list is not just **/usr/maxigent50**.
its original full command is **/usr/maxigent50/bin/mxPERF**
this means that the '/bin/mxPERF' part of the full command was not showed in the ps -ef command results.
FYI, I made this daemon with C++ compiled by Xlc on AIX.

Why?
What dose make this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, No. It seems not a displaying size problem. if it was, then the whole commands of result of the ps -ef command should have the same problem. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Does your daemon change the memory at argv[0]? For example do you set a null byte at one of the '/' characters to extract a path?

Comment: Oh!! Yes, It dose!! I've never thought about it. Thank you very much!!! You're my hero. :-D